# Assembly strings and equivalent code in C++

Tags: c++, string, assembly

I've got some code in assembly:

```
et:
s db 'text'
s_size = $ - et
  db 0Dh,0Ah,'$'
```

I would like to ask what do `s_size = $ - et` and `db 0Dh,0Ah,'$'` do?
I also wonder what would be the equivalent code of these definitions in C++?

Comment: What you can always do with such small programs is run it, and then inspect the output and basically reverse engineer it based on input/output.

Comment: It says `size` ... so what do you think it is? Also, look up what `$` means in your assembler's manual. An ascii table will tell you what `0d` and `0a` are if you have never seen those. The `'$'` at the end is just that, a literal `$` sign (it's used by some old dos functions to denote end of string but of course you didn't mention you were using dos ...)

Comment: In C++ you just do `std::string s = "text";` and then you can get the size as `s.size()`. Simple, isn't it! The hex combo makes a newline which is written as `'\n'` in C or C++.

Comment: BTW symbol `et` is basically identical to `s`. ... it's redundant to have two symbols pointing at the same address in memory (although it doesn't hurt either, JFYI that using the `s` in size calculation would be enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is current address.
`db` is the command to `d`efine `b`ytes.
`et` is the label and as such the address where the string `text` is starting.
`$ - et` is current address - address of start of string. As the command is right after the string, this means: length of the string.
`0D 0A` are carriage return and line feed ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
s_size = $ - et
```

My guess is that `$` marks the offset (memory address) of the current statement, and that `$ - et` is the distance/size in bytes between the two code locations, 'et' being a label. I've never used $ this way myself before, but a book on MASM should be able to confirm that.

```
db 0Dh,0Ah,'$'
```

This dumps the bytes Carriage Return (0Dh), Line Feed (0Ah) and the literal '$' into memory. As the previous poster stated, "The '$' at the end is just that, a literal $ sign...." and yes, it is used to indicate the end of a string that would be displayed by an `INT 21H` call; I believe it is sub function 9.